# Can't simplify topojson for d3 mapping

Tags: json, d3.js, mapping, topojson

I'm trying to map some statistical data of Italy and I need the infrastructure (railway and motorway) on top of it.
The problem is that I'm not able to simplify the infrastructure json file.
I'm using the openstreetmap shape of Italy by geofabbriK: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html#

I've converted the roads.shp to json selecting only motorway and and primary roads using this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -where "type IN ('motorway', 'motorway_link', 'primary', 'primary_link')" -t_srs EPSG:4326 roads.json roads.shp
```

I get a 55Mb json file. You can download it here: http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/roads_mw_pr.zip

Than I tryed to simplify and convert it in topojson. 
Whit no -s command the new json file is about 13Mb
If I use -s or --simplify-proportion with any value form 1 to 0 I always get a max semplification of 95% and a filesize of 11Mb

How can I get a more simplified topojson?

Thanks
daniele

Comment: I would simplify the geometry before passing it to TopoJSON with a GIS program such as [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Comment: Hmmmm this could be a solution... But are you sudjesting this because it not possible with topojson? or because just is easier in qgis? Anyway... How could I simplify paths in qgis? thanks!

Comment: You can do it in TopoJSON as well, see [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/). I just prefer QGIS because that's where I would do the heavy-lifting stuff. See [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/how-to-smooth-generalize-a-polygon-in-qgis) for how to simplify paths.

Comment: I'll try with qgis. About TopoJson I tried to follow the link you posted and I read the wiki but it seems the -s or --simplify-proportion didn't affect the original json... Have you any advice or tutorial on how to use this command? (I used --simplify-proportion with 0.5 value, or less, on other json and it works fine)

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of very small features in this dataset that can't be simplified, so you hit a minimum file size pretty quickly. Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might get away with just deleting these small features from the shapefile before converting to TopoJSON (use `$length<0.001` in the QGIS "Select by Expression" dialog, for example). Note that this will cause some gaps in the roads, though.

Comment: Also, if this is just for a small scale map and not for analysis, it's probably a better idea to start with generalised data, and not the full-blown OSM data. Natural Earth has [roads](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/roads/) and [railroads](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/railroads/) for the entire globe, or you can take a look at the open data at the [EuroGlobalMap](http://www.eurogeographics.org/products-and-services/euroglobalmap) project by the European Union.

Comment: Thanks jake for the link! I didn't konw these dataset! I'm making a try with EuroGlobalMap shape.

Comment: here my firs try using EuroGlobalMap, Thanks again! http://www.danielepennati.com/prove/mapping/ita_pop_den.html